# KafkaError Unsupported compression codec 0x3 with Confluent Python Kafka consumer

Tags: python, linux, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I set up Confluent Python Kafka consumer on my laptop (Ubuntu 17) and everything is fine, I can listen to remote topics and receive messages.

But when I try to set it up on a server (Ubuntu 16), there is what seems to be a compression issue. The data comes from Divolte and is compressed with LZ4.

The data is received successfully without any error when first connecting to a topic, but after closing and re-opening the consumer, a first message is received and an error is thrown:

```
<cimpl.Message object at 0x7f089db67180>
KafkaError{code=_NOT_IMPLEMENTED,val=-170,str="Unsupported compression codec 0x3"}
```

I think it's not from Divolte data source but more like a message from Kafka, but I cannot read its value since the error happens before (msg is printed and then we jump to elif for the error):

```
c = Consumer({'bootstrap.servers': server['server'], 'group.id': 'mygroup',
              'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'smallest'}})
c.subscribe([server['topic']])
running = True
while running:
    msg = c.poll()
    print(msg)
    if not msg.error():
        msg_value = msg.value()
        print(msg_value)
    elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
        print(msg.error())
        running = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it seemed like a version problem but 0.10 was not necessary apparently, I followed http://docs.confluent.io/current/installation.html to reinstall the repository and confluent platform, then updated librdkafka1 and librdkafka-dev from 0.9.1 to 0.9.5 and it solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this problem which should be fixed in 0.10.0 or higher

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3160